# JQuery: $(this) retorna r.fn.init [Window] en vez de un botón

Tags: jquery

Al parecer cuando escucho la acción del buton con la clase eliminar si realiza la accion pero el `$(this)` me retorna `r.fn.init [Window]` y no sé por qué.

Este es mi html:

```
              <form id="task-form">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="number" id="id" placeholder="codigo" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="number" id="cantidad" placeholder="cantidad" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center">
                  Agregar
                </button>
              </form>


        <div class="col-md-7">
       <div class="bg-white">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td>N°</td>
                        <td>Codigo</td>
                <td>Producto</td>
                <td>Cantidad</td>
                        <td>Precio</td>
                <td>Total</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tasks"></tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Aquí comienzan mis scripts y establezco el contenido de mi tabla:

```js
let productos ='';
let i = 1;
$('#task-form').submit(e => {
 e.preventDefault();
  const postData = {
   id: $('#id').val(),
   cantidad: $('#cantidad').val(),
 };
 console.log(postData);
 $.post("<?=base_url?>listar.php", postData, (response) => {
  const prod = JSON.parse(response);
  console.log(prod);
        prod.forEach(prod => {
          productos += `
                  <tr taskId="${i}">
                  <td>${i}</td>
                  <td>${prod.nombre}</td>
                  <td>${prod.cantidad}</td>
      <td>${prod.precio}</td>
                  <td>${prod.total}</td>
                  <td>
                    <button class="eliminar btn btn-danger">
                     Delete 
                    </button>
                  </td>
                  </tr>
                `
   });
      i++;
        $('#tasks').html(productos);
  $('#task-form').trigger('reset');
 });
})
```

Este script llama al elemento que me está desencadenando la acción:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.eliminar', (e) => {
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete it?')) {
      console.log($(this));
    }
  });
```

> Quiero escuchar el botón que que me está mandando la accion o evento
>   el cual tiene la clase eliminar pero el `$(this)` me retorna r.fn.init
>   [Window]

Este es el archivo listar.php en el cual leo el json y lo envío en modo string:

Conexión a base de datos:

```
include('conec.php');
```

Guardo las variables enviadas por post:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

$cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];

Valido los datos en una consulta:

```
$query = "SELECT * from productos WHERE id_prod=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);



  if(!$result) {
die('Query Failed'. mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Si es válido realizo el siguiente proceso donde recorro el objeto de consulta y asigno a cada propiedad de mi objeto un valor de los campos de la variable de consulta.

Inicio el json:

```
$json= array();
```

ahora recorro las filas

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$json[] = array(
    'id' => $row['id_prod'],
    'nombre' => $row['nombre_prod'],
    'precio' => $row['precioV_prod'],
    'cantidad' => $cantidad,
    'total' => (($cantidad)*($row['precioV_prod']))
); 
}
```

Ahora lo retorno al script:

```
$jsonstring = json_encode($json);
echo $jsonstring;
```

Comment: Si quieres ayuda, podrias compartir el codigo con el cual estas trabajando.

Comment: ok ahora lo hago

Comment: puedes obtener el elemento seleccionado cambiando `$(this)` por `e.target` que es lo mismo!

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener el boton seleccionado tendrias que utilizar la funcion de esta forma, en este caso para poder utilizar el `this` no debes usar la funcion de fecha.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).on('click', '.eliminar', function() {
    let id = $(this).data('id');
    console.log('Ejemplo 1', id, $(this));
  });
  
  
$(document).on('click', '.eliminar', (e) => {
    let id = $(e.currentTarget).data('id');
    console.log('Ejemplo 2 con function => ',id, $(this));
  });  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="eliminar" data-id="1">Boton 1</button>
<button class="eliminar" data-id="2">Boton 2</button>
```

En el ejemplo 2 para utilizarlo con la funcion de fecha, deberas obtener el boton de esta forma  `e.currentTarget`

espero te sirva.

Comment: me sirvio ahora ¿puedo usar parent para llegar al padre que tenga un id especifico
      let id = $(this).data('id').activeElement.parentElement.parentElement;
      const ele = $(id).attr('taskId');

Comment: edite mi respuesta, para que puedas utilizar la funcion de fecha, oteniendo el boton con `e.currentTarget`, saludos

Comment: como obtengo en este mismo codigo en td que tiene el taskId="${i}"

Comment: como obtengo en este mismo codigo en td que tiene el taskId="${i}"

Comment: te recomiendo mejor agregar un `data` al boton como en el ejemplo, en vez de agregarselo al `tr`, seria `data-id="${i}"` en el boton

Comment: Ya he resuelto el problema gracias a los que me ayudaron apenas llevo 2 dias en jquery y ajax